# {Help} FFMPEG with NVIDIA hardware acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, nvidia

I just started using ffmpeg so I am new this. I am currently (code-1) to overlay a simple png on a video nothing fancy.

Now I want to the same thing but with hardware acceleration using a NVIDIA GPU. But I am clue less as to how to go about it. Can you please tell me how to do this.

FFMPEG is the latest version and my gpu is supported plus i have all the latest drivers and the cuda support.

```
!ffmpeg -i /content/tst.mp4 -vf "movie=/content/over1.png[img01];[in][img01]overlay[out]" output.mp4
```